# Vertical align string in Tkinter Radiobutton with specified width

Tags: python, tkinter, string-formatting

I need help aligning a string in a Tkinter `Radiobutton`

[image: Window]

As you can see, it is not perfectly aligned. How can I get the "Goal" text to be vertically aligned? I am doing it like this:

```
pairs = [None for x in range(10)]
for i in range(len(startList)):
  pairs[i] = (''.join(["Start: (", str(startList[i].X), ",", str(startList[i]), ")", '{:>20}'.format(''.join(["Goal: (", str(goalList[i].X), ",", str(goalList[i].Y), ")"]))]), i)

radioRow = Frame(self)
radioRow.pack(fill=Y)
v = IntVar()
v.set(0)

for text, mode in pairs:
    rdButton = Radiobutton(radioRow, text=text, variable=v, value=mode)
rdButton.pack(anchor=W)
```

Comment: it can work only with monospaced font which has all chars the same width.

Comment: you have to justify `Start`, not `Goal` - Start has to use always 20 chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate the text into two widgets: a radiobutton and a label. Then make the parent of the radiobuttons and labels a frame, and use `grid` to arrange them in a two column by ten row matrix.

Here's a rough example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

data = (
    ((111,2), (14,90)),
    ((46, 1), (16, 111)),
    ((94, 1), (16, 111)),
)

root = tk.Tk()
choices = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
choices.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

v = tk.StringVar()
for row, (start, goal) in enumerate(data):
    button = tk.Radiobutton(choices, text="Start (%s,%s)" % start, value=start, variable=v)
    label = tk.Label(choices, text="Goal: (%s, %s)" % goal)
    button.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky="w")
    label.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky="w")

# give the invisible row below the last row a weight, so any
# extra space is given to it
choices.grid_rowconfigure(row+1, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you know why when I do `v.get()`, I get `0` back no matter what radio button I choose?

Comment: @cress: no, I don't because I can't see your code. Though, it might be because I gave the radiobuttons string values but tied it to an `IntVar`. When I change the `IntVar` to a `StringVar` it works just fine. I changed my example to use a `StringVar`. You can use an `IntVar` of course, as long as the radiobuttons each have an integer as the value.

Comment: I have mostly your code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/590324207d70cf29f95f7b98fc7e9624 (I have that `print` statement inside a function that gets called when I click a button). I assigned the value to be `row`, so it goes from 0-9.

Comment: In your gist, you haven't given the variable a value so it defaults to zero. Why is that surprising?

Comment: I don't understand. Should I make a list with values from 0-9 and put that in for `variable`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to align `Start`, not `Goal` - `{:<10}` - so it will use always 10 chars. And then `Goal` will start in the same place. But it will work ideally only with monospaced fonts

```
data = [
    (111, 2, 14, 90),
    (46, 1, 16, 111),
    (94, 1, 38, 1),
]

for a, b, c, d in data:    
    start = "({},{})".format(a, b)
    goal  = "({},{})".format(c, d)

    print("Start: {:<10} Goal: {}".format(start, goal))
```

Result:

```
Start: (111,2)    Goal: (14,90)
Start: (46,1)     Goal: (16,111)
Start: (94,1)     Goal: (38,1)
```

---

**BTW:** You can also use `grid()` to create two columns - one with `Radiobutton` and `Start`, second with `Label` and `Goal`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How do I set the font for the `Radiobuttons`? I looked it up and examples tell me to `import tkFont`, but I get an error saying that module doesn't exist.

Comment: if you use Python 3 then `import tkinter.font as tkFont`

Comment: or directly `tk.Radiobutton( ..., font=("Courier", 36, "bold"))`

Comment: It says `-font` is an unknown option.

Comment: because you use `ttk`, not `tk` - `ttk.Radiobutton`, not `tk.Radiobutton` - you have to use `Styles`

Comment: Got it to work using the Monospaced font as well. Thanks!